# How to generate TypeScript code coverage with Mocha

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, istanbul

I am using mocha in combination with Istanbul and I am starting getting around to TypeScript. Running mocha tests in combination with `ts-node` isn't a problem. The problem lies within getting Istanbul to work with TypeScript. Are there any tools within the Gulp environment to make this work?

**Istanbul task**

```
//This task was written before typescript
//Paths is a JSON object which contains all paths
//ISparta to convert it to ES5 compatible code

gulp.task('istanbul', () => {
    return gulp.src([paths.source.ecmascript])
        .pipe(istanbul({
            includeUntested: true,
            instrumenter: isparta.Instrumenter
        }))
        .pipe(istanbul.hookRequire())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.coverage));
});
```

**Mocha task**

```
//Currently working version with typescript

require('ts-node/register');

gulp.task('mocha', [], () => {
    return gulp.src([paths.test], {read: false})
        .pipe(mocha({
            reporter: 'spec',
            timeout: 5000,
            bail: false
        }))
        /*
        .pipe(istanbul.writeReports({
            reporters: ['lcov', 'json', 'text-summary']
        }))
        */
        .once('error', () => {
            process.exit(1);
        })
        .once('exit', () => {
            process.exit();
        })
        .on('error', gulpUtil.log);
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at [https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/212](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/212)? There's also an example there how to get this to work without gulp. You'd need Istanbul 1.x though.

Comment: @Izhaki The newest alpha works with Typescript, the problem is that I want it to work in the Gulp environment.

Comment: @GamerNebulae if you are still looking for a solution, please check this repository https://github.com/jsynowiec/node-typescript-boilerplate. It's an example Node.js TypeScript boilerplate with Mocha tests and Istanbul coverage. I'm not using Gulp though.